# Display map tips of superimposed points

Tags: qgis, point, maptips

I have created a tabular listing of selected attributes in QGIS as map tips via HTML script. Unfortunately only the information of the uppermost point is shown.

Is there a possibility to display map tips of superimposed points, which are displayed with point displacement?

[image: Example 1]

In my opinion, there is no keyboard combination in QGIS to jump to the next marked point for displaying its attributes.

However,the plugin ["eVis"](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/plugins/evis) is able to select individual points lying on top of each other using the forward- and back-button.

Is it possible to integrate these buttons into the HTML script?

[image: Example 2]

Here is the source code of the script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
       table {width: 300px}
       table, th, td {
            border-collapse:    collapse;
            text-align:         left;
            padding:            1px;
            font-family:        Calibri;
            color:              #000000;
            font-size:          11px
            }
            tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color:   #e9f0f9
            }
            a.kopfzeile        {color: #FFFFFF;
                                text-decoration: none;}
            a.kopfzeile:hover  {background-color:   #2E60AB;
                                display:block;
                                height: 13px; /*höhe der Linkboxen*/
                                line-height: 13px; /*Text innerhalb der Linkbox*/
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                font-weight: bold} 
            a.kopfzeile:active {background-color:   #2E60AB;
                                display:block;
                                height: 13px;
                                line-height: 13px;
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                font-weight: bold}

            a.foto:hover    {background-color:  #E5E5E5;
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                font-weight: bold} 
            a.foto:active   {color: blue;
                                background-color:   #E5E5E5;
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                font-weight: bold}

                        img {display: none; width: 296px; max-height: 292px; object-fit: cover; position: absolute; top: 13px; left: 0px; border: 2px solid #356ec5; background: white}
            a:hover img {display: block; }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2" bgcolor="#356ec5"><a class="kopfzeile" href=http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/datenblaetter_voe/[% replace("Datenblatt",' ','%20') %]
            >HWM [% "Lfd__Nr_" %] – [% "Gewässer" %] 
[% CASE 
WHEN  "Monat" = '01'  THEN 'Jan.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '02'  THEN 'Feb.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '03'  THEN 'März'
WHEN  "Monat" = '04'  THEN 'April'
WHEN  "Monat" = '05'  THEN 'Mai'
WHEN  "Monat" = '06'  THEN 'Juni'
WHEN  "Monat" = '07'  THEN 'Juli'
WHEN  "Monat" = '08'  THEN 'Aug.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '09'  THEN 'Sep.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '10'  THEN 'Okt.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '11'  THEN 'Nov.'
WHEN  "Monat" = '12'  THEN 'Dez.'
END %] 
[% "Jahr" %]</a></th>
    </tr>

<tr><td width="33%">Lfd.-Nr.:</td><td width="67%">[% "Lfd__Nr_" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ereignisjahr:</td><td>[% "Jahr" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Datum:</td><td>
[% if( "Tag" IS NOT NULL AND "Tag" <> 0,"Tag"||'.','') %]
[% if(("Monat" IS NOT NULL AND "Monat" <> 0),CASE 
WHEN  "Monat" = '01'  THEN 'Januar'
WHEN  "Monat" = '02'  THEN 'Februar'
WHEN  "Monat" = '03'  THEN 'März'
WHEN  "Monat" = '04'  THEN 'April'
WHEN  "Monat" = '05'  THEN 'Mai'
WHEN  "Monat" = '06'  THEN 'Juni'
WHEN  "Monat" = '07'  THEN 'Juli'
WHEN  "Monat" = '08'  THEN 'August'
WHEN  "Monat" = '09'  THEN 'September'
WHEN  "Monat" = '10'  THEN 'Oktober'
WHEN  "Monat" = '11'  THEN 'November'
WHEN  "Monat" = '12'  THEN 'Dezember'
END,'') %]
[% if(("Tag" IS NULL OR "Tag" = 0) AND ("Monat" IS NULL OR "Monat" = 0),'–','') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Gewässer:</td><td>[% "Gewässer" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Gewässerordnung:</td><td>[% "Ordnung" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Gewässerkennzahl:</td><td>[% "Gewässerke" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Stationierung:</td><td>[% if( "Stationier" IS NULL OR "Stationier" = 0,'–',replace("Stationier" , '.',',')||char(8239)||'km') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Uferseite:</td><td>[% "Uferseite" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>GK4-Koordinaten:<br>(DHDN RD/83) </td><td>[% replace("Rechtswert" , '.',',') %]<br>[% replace("Hochwert" , '.',',') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>UTM-Koordinaten:<br>(ETRS89 UTM33N) </td><td>[% replace("Ostwert" , '.',',') %]<br>[% replace("Nordwert" , '.',',') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>geogr. Koordinaten:<br>(ETRS89) </td><td>[% replace("Längengrad" , '.',',') %]°<br>[% replace("Breitengra" , '.',',') %]°</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Wasserstand:</td><td>
[% if( "Wasserstan" IS NOT NULL AND "Wasserstan" <> 0,replace("Wasserstan" ,'.',',')||char(8239)||'m'||char(8239)||'ü.'||char(8239)||'NHN'||char(8195),'') %]
[% if( "Wasserst_1" IS NOT NULL AND "Wasserst_1" <> 0,replace("Wasserst_1" ,'.',',')||char(8239)||'m'||char(8239)||'ü.'||char(8239)||'HN'||char(8195),'') %]
[% if( "Wasserst_2" IS NOT NULL AND "Wasserst_2" <> 0,replace("Wasserst_2" ,'.',',')||char(8239)||'m'||char(8239)||'ü.'||char(8239)||'NN'||char(8195),'') %]
[% if( "Wasserst_3" IS NOT NULL AND "Wasserst_3" <> 0,replace("Wasserst_3" ,'.',',')||char(8239)||'m'||char(8239)||'ü.'||char(8239)||'GOK','') %]
[% if(("Wasserstan" IS NULL OR "Wasserstan" = 0) AND ("Wasserst_1" IS NULL OR "Wasserst_1" = 0) AND ("Wasserst_2" IS NULL OR "Wasserst_2" = 0) AND ("Wasserst_3" IS NULL OR "Wasserst_3" = 0),'–','') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Landkreis:</td><td>[% "Landkreis" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Gemeinde:</td><td>[% "Gemeinde" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Gemarkung:</td><td>[% "Gemarkung" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Ortslage:</td><td>[% "Ortslage_A" %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Art der Marke:</td><td>[% if("Art_der_Ho" IS NULL, '–', "Art_der_Ho") %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Fotos:</td><td>[% if("Foto_1" IS NOT NULL AND "Foto_1" <> 0,'<a class="foto" href=http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_1"||'>Foto 1<img src="http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_1"||'"></a>','') %]
[% if("Foto_2" IS NOT NULL AND "Foto_2" <> 0, char(8195)||'<a class="foto" href=http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_2"||'>Foto 2<img src="http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_2"||'"></a>','') %]
[% if("Foto_3" IS NOT NULL AND "Foto_3" <> 0,char(8195)||'<a class="foto" href=http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_3"||'>Foto 3<img src="http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_3"||'"></a>','') %]
[% if("Foto_4" IS NOT NULL AND "Foto_4" <> 0,char(8195)||'<a class="foto" href=http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_4"||'>Foto 4<img src="http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/ags/hochwassermarken/fotos/veroeffentlichung/dateien/fotos_voe/'||"Foto_4"||'"></a>','') %]
[% if(("Foto_1" IS NULL OR "Foto_1" = 0) AND ("Foto_2" IS NULL OR "Foto_2" = 0) AND ("Foto_3" IS NULL OR "Foto_3" = 0) AND ("Foto_4" IS NULL OR "Foto_4" = 0),'–','') %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Herausgeber:</td><td>[% if("Auftraggeb" IS NULL, '–', "Auftraggeb") %]</td></tr>
<tr><td valign=top>Erfasser:</td><td>[% if("Aufgenomme" IS NULL, '–', "Aufgenomme") %]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Datenstand:</td><td>August 2015</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

My programming skills are unfortunately very limited.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.